# jQuery fadeTo. Fades div and h1

Tags: jquery, html

I want to just fade the div. This code fades the div and the writing inside it.
So the writing goes grey even though I want it to stay black.

```
<body>
    <div id="bc"><h1>Welcome Russell!</h1></div>
</body>
```

If I take the h1 out of the div it will look like

---

"""""""""""""""""""""""
|"No Writing Here"|

"""""""""""""""""""""""
My Header Here

---

But I want it like this
"""""""""""""""""""""""
|"My Header Here"|

"""""""""""""""""""""""

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").mouseover(function(){
        $("#bc").fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
});
    $("div").mouseout(function(){
        $("#bc").fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
```

Comment: This is how it's supposed to work, when a parent element has opacity of 0.5 it's descendant inherit that property too.

Comment: yeah, but is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There's nothing to fix, that's the expected behavior. You'd need to change your HTML structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it's supposed to work, when a parent element has opacity of 0.5 it's descendant inherit that property too. If you want to change the background-color of the DIV element you can use a `rgba` value and `css` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", 'rgba(0,0,0, 1)');
    });
});
```

**Note**: If you want to animate background-color of an element you should load jQuery UI.

You can also use CSS3 transition property:

```
div {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    color: white;
    -moz-transition: .5s background-color;
    -webkit-transition: .5s background-color;
    -o-transition: .5s background-color;
    transition: .5s background-color;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vyBgW/

Comment: I already tried the first one but I'm looking for animation... so the second one is perfect! :) thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also include jQuery UI, which lets you animate properties such as background-color.

Then, your code could look something like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").mouseover(function(){
        $("#bc").animate({backgroundColor: "Red"});

});
    $("div").mouseout(function(){
        $("#bc").animate({backgroundColor: "Gray"});
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BrN4t/

Obviously, you should change the colors to change to to suit you better.  My example just shows the basics of how it works.